# Need Help Nginx phpmyadmin Ubuntu 14.04, cant run web1.com/phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress, nginx, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

I am newbie in this. I am trying to setup 3 wordpress sites using their own domain name on digitalocean.
I followed their tutorial, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-single-and-multiple-wordpress-site-settings-with-nginx

I did install 2 wordpress and was able to run them with no problem.
But now I need to install phpmyadmin so I followed this tutorial but I didnt do the secure part yet, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

Right now when I try to run web1.com/info.php and web1.com/phpmyadmin, I get 404 error with wordpress theme.

I put wordpress installation in /home/ap/web1 and /home/ap/web2

```
server {
server_name web1.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.web1.com$request_uri;
    }
server_name www.web1.com;
root /home/ap/web1;
access_log /var/log/nginx/www.web1.com.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/www.web1.com.error.log;

    location /phpmyadmin{
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
    include global/common.conf;
    include global/wordpress.conf;
    include global/multisite.conf;
}
```

What do I need to fix?

Comment: Have you tried to use `root` instead of `alias` in `location /phpadmin` ?

Comment: i had already tried but didnt work

Comment: So let's try to add in this location the parameters used in .php$ location, something like: 

```include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  backendPool;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    ```

Comment: do u mean this one?
'location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }'

this one is on  /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

Comment: Do I put your code just after'include global/multisite.conf;' ? I did that and I wasnt able to restart nginx

Comment: No, just put my code inside the `location /phpmyadmin` block.

Comment: I put your code inside /phpmyadmin block just before '{' and I couldnt restart nginx

Comment: No, use this:
location /phpmyadmin {
     fastcgi_pass  backendPool;
     fastcgi_index index.php; 
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
}

Please, read the nginx manual.

Comment: It doesnt work. same error cant restart nginx

Comment: Have you defined backendPool? Have you read nginx manual?

Comment: i have not read the manual yet. I thought I followed the tutorial was enough and this should be easy fix. So I need to read the manual about setting up backendpool?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix this by `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /home/ap/web1` . Previously, I followed tutorial and did this `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /usr/share/nginx/html`